# If statement in sql query with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, inner-join

I am sorry, I know there is a lot of answer on the forum concerning that question but I didn't succeed to adapt an answer to my problem.

Here is my function :

```
public function getPupil($db, $pupil_id){
    $pupil = $db->query('
        SELECT 
        a.gender as genderPupil,
        pupil_name, 
        pupil_lastname,
        a.id as pupilId, 
        b.id as idOne, 
        c.id as idTwo, 
        b.lastname as lastnameOne, 
        b.name as nameOne, 
        c.name as nameTwo, 
        c.lastname as lastnameTwo,
        birthdate,
        school,
        level,
        allergies,
        special_diet,
        tap,
        d.name as tapNameFirstTerm,
        e.name as tapNameSecondTerm,
        f.name as tapNameThirdTerm

        FROM pupils a
        INNER JOIN responsibles b ON a.id_responsibles = b.id
        INNER JOIN responsibles c ON a.id_responsibles_two = c.id
        INNER JOIN tap_activities d ON a.tap_first_term = d.id
        INNER JOIN tap_activities e ON a.tap_second_term = e.id 
        INNER JOIN tap_activities f ON a.tap_third_term = f.id
        WHERE a.id = ?
        ', [$pupil_id])->fetch();
    return $pupil;
}
```

I would like to add conditions to do not query the INNER JOIN when a.tap_first_term or a.tap_second_term or a.tap_third_term are equal to 0.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Which inner join? You have several. Also, are you sure that's where it would go? You're testing against a column in the FROM table? Unless it's dependent on a value in one of the JOIN tables, it would go in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. 
For the people that could be interested, I just changed the three INNER JOIN for the tap_activities by LEFT JOIN. And it works as I want.